# Meaning of 巡り合う好機 in this passage

Tags: words, particle-は, relative-clauses

A passage from the first chapter of 夜は短し歩けよ乙女 by 森見登美彦:

> ⁠　あな恐ろしやと思いながら肩身の狭い思いをしてカウンターをすり抜けると、その奥に隠れ家のような薄暗い空間があって、羽貫さんが四人のナイスミドルの方々に交じってお喋りしていました。
> 　紅い布張りのソファに座ったおじさん方は、皆さん紅いネクタイを締めています。**巡り合う好機**はことごとく酒瓶に変えて憂うことのない羽貫さんは早々とその紅ネクタイのおじさん方と意気投合しているようなのです。

What does 巡り合う好機 mean?

- A good chance to meet someone?
- The good chance (for something to happen) that is meeting someone? (equivalence)
- A good chance that you happen across? Or that happens across you?

Is 好機 the direct object of 変える?

Does 巡り合う好機はことごとく酒瓶に変えて憂うことのない, as a whole, modify 羽貫さん? (Even though it contains は)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does 巡り合う好機はことごとく酒瓶に変えて憂うことのない, as a whole, modify 羽貫さん?

Yes.

> Is 好機 the direct object of 変える?

Yes.

> What does 巡り合う好機 mean?

It means 'Good chance which Ms. Hanuki encounters.', and this chance is for getting a drink from someone.

This sentence,

> 巡り合う好機はことごとく酒瓶に変えて憂うことのない羽貫さんは早々とその紅ネクタイのおじさん方と意気投合しているようなのです。

is equivalent to

- 羽貫さんは、巡り合う好機はことごとく酒瓶に変えて憂うことがありません。
- 羽貫さんは早々とその紅ネクタイのおじさん方と意気投合しているようなのです。

and to

- 羽貫さんは、巡り合う好機をことごとく酒瓶に変えます。そして、そうすることを憂いません。
- 羽貫さんは早々とその紅ネクタイのおじさん方と意気投合しているようなのです。

The sentence means

- Ms. Hanuki does not hesitate to utilize all the chances she can get to drink.
- Ms. Hanuki seems to have already made friends with those gentlemen wearing the red ties.

好機を酒瓶に変える is the author's own elegant rhetoric, and it'd be expressed as 機会さえあれば、酒を飲む or 酒をおごってもらう機会を目ざとく見つける in daily language.